# Acrobat XI Pro: Moving text in front of drawing markups

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I want to put a caption on a photograph.  Text to be white.  Due to the complex background it's hard to read.  I'm drawing a black oval 70% opaque and want to put white text over the oval.  Oval always on top of text. ARRANGE/BRING TO FRONT does nothing to the text and that option is not available on the oval and hides the text.  Do I have to use 'layers' somehow? How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I created a WHITE RECTANGLE to cover previous (embedded and uneditable) text. But every new text object I create goes BEHIND the Rectangle. Nothing I do can re-arrange that.

Comment: It actually appears to be impossible to do this very simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

The new Acrobat Pro-DC (April 2015) does not seem to have this problem.  The object that is created last (text vs rectangle) will be on top.

Comment: Hopefully, this thread will be around for a long time.  "new" won't mean much.  Can you edit your answer to specify a version number?

Comment: I think "DC" is the version.  Creative Cloud Acrobat Pro-DC released April 2015

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I still have seen no official solution to this.

But I have found some work-arounds. I create a "Text Box" (under "Drawing Markups"), instead of using "Add Text". the Text Box tool allows for a background color. To lay one text on top of another, create the "Text Box" to the size you need, and select a white background (Tool Properties), then add text. To change the look of the text, highlight just the text and Ctrl-E to edit the text format/font/color etc.